# Access the values of res/values/strings

Tags: android, android-resources

I read about [String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) and I understood that you simply use the `getString(...)` method in order to read the value of a string from `res/values/string.xml`. Then I read that you can also use `getResources().getString(...)`.

What is the difference between these two ways of obtaining the value of a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No any difference. They're both equal.